# Using IF ELSE condition from another method C# or VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I know this question maybe super easy to some so please don't eat my head for asking, but I have been struggling to figure this out:

I will like to use the condition from IF Else statement from a different method to redirect user to different pages based on if they pass or fail. this is what my code looks like:

```
    Public passScore As Boolean

    Public Sub BindGrid()
    .....
        If calcTotal >= 70 Then
            passScore = True
            btnNext.Visible = True
        Else
            passScore = False
            btnNext.Visible = False
        End If


    End Sub
```

this is where I am struggling.. being able to use the result from the calculation to redirect user after the click a button:

```
Protected Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click


        If passScore = True Then
            Response.Redirect(mstrPassSlide, False)
        else
            Response.Redirect(mstrFailSlide, False)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally

End Sub
```

New Code Changes

I tried the suggestion below and now the database object I am using for the calculation is returning NULL. I changed the method from 'Sub' to 'Function'

```
Public Function CalculateTotal() As Integer
    Dim objDatabase As BTTQAResults

    Try
        objDatabase = CType(Cache("QAResults"), BTTQAResults)
        Dim calcTotal As Integer
        For index As Integer = 0 To objDatabase.Count - 1
            calcTotal = calcTotal + objDatabase(index).Mark
        Next
        calcTotal = CInt((calcTotal / objDatabase.Count) * 100)

        Part1QAResult.DataSource = objDatabase
        Part1QAResult.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionManager.Publish(ex)
        Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx", False)
    End Try
End Function
```

objDatabase = CType(Cache("QAResults"), BTTQAResults) is NULL

Comment: As @TimSchmelter said, it is unclear. Please read ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You could make `passScore` a property based on the value of `calcTotal`, and if it's not already, make `calcTotal` a separate property (or method). That way you can use them from multiple methods rather than just `BindGrid`.

Comment: @RufusL can you please give an example

Comment: Sure, I added one below

Comment: @RufusL Please I still need help figuring out how to separate the method with the  database object and the calculations. I am stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to separate your logic into small method to make the code reusable. Or put it inside classes.

```
   Public Function CalculateTotal() As Integer
      ' ...
   End Function

   Public Function IsTotalPassScore() As Boolean
      Return CalculateTotal() >= 70
   End Function

   Public Sub BindGrid()
        If IsTotalPassScore() Then
            btnNext.Visible = True
        Else
            btnNext.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        If IsTotalPassScore() Then
            Response.Redirect(mstrPassSlide, False)
        End If

        Response.Redirect(mstrFailSlide, False)
    End Sub
```

If the calculation takes some time, it could be done in the OnInit and the result stored somewhere.

Comment: Hi, I was using your method but the database object I am using for the calculation is returning NULL. I changed the method from 'Sub' to 'Function'. I updated the original question. Please advice

Comment: @SeleniumNewGuy your new CalculateTotal method is doing to much. It isn't just calculating the total, it is also setting the datasource.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to also set the database, I  did not think I needed to share too much code initially. My bad

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have figured out my issue. This helped a l lot

Answer (score 2):

When you find yourself wanting to use a portion of logic from one method in another method, this usually indicates that the logic should be refactored into it's own method so it can be called from multiple places.

In this case we may be able to use two read-only properties, for example:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property CalcTotal() As Integer
    Get
        'Do some calculation here
        Return result
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property PassScore() As Boolean
    Get
        Return CalcTotal >= 70
    End Get
End Property
```

Now either of these properties can be called from any method in the class.

Comment: Hi, I was using this approach, it is similar to the one @the_lotus suggested but the database object I am using for the calculation is returning NULL. I changed the method from 'Sub' to 'Function'. I updated the original question. Please advice

Comment: My bad I did not think I needed to share those information initially

Answer (score 0):

You should try to Call the BindGrid() method at your click event.

```
Protected Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click

    BindGrid()
    If passScore = True Then
        Response.Redirect(mstrPassSlide, False)
    End If


    'Response.Redirect(mstrFailSlide, False)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that, it is not working. It fails at the BindGrid() 
Exception Information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Target Site: Void BindGrid()

Comment: This must be a data problem. the data you are trying to retrieve does not exist in your database.